# Parent-query in prolog does not return ALL parentships

Tags: prolog

Given these facts:

```
male(jerry).
male(stuart).
male(warren).
male(peter).
female(kather).
female(maryalice).
female(ann).
brother(jerry,stuart).
brother(jerry,kather).
brother(peter, warren).
sister(ann, maryalice).    
sister(kather,jerry).
parent_of(warren,jerry).
parent_of(maryalice,jerry).
```

As you can see warren and maryalice are parents of jerry, stuart and kather. What rules will I need to implement in order for the query `parent_of(X,Y).` to return

```
X=warren, Y=jerry
X=warren, Y=stuart
X=warren, Y=kather
X=maryalice, Y=jerry
X=maryalice, Y=stuart
X=maryalice, Y=kather
```

i.e all the parenthood relationships?

I have tried

```
parent_of(X,Y) :- parent_of(X,C), sibling(Y,C), X \= Y.
sibling(C,OC) :- brother(C,OC), C \= OC.
sibling(C,OC) :- sister(C,OC), C \= OC.
```

but querying `parent_of(X,Y).` returns this

```
X = warren,
Y = jerry ;
X = maryalice,
Y = jerry ;
X = warren,
Y = kather ;
X = maryalice,
Y = kather ;
X = warren,
Y = jerry ;
X = maryalice,
Y = jerry ;
X = warren,
Y = kather ;
X = maryalice,
Y = kather ;
X = warren,
Y = jerry ;
X = maryalice,
Y = jerry ;
X = warren,
Y = kather ;
X = maryalice,
Y = kather ;
X = warren,
Y = jerry ;
X = maryalice,
Y = jerry ;
X = warren,
Y = kather ;
........
```

Where the parenthood between warren and stuart and maryalice and stuart is missin (and it is also stuck in some kind of loop!).

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate the fact `parent_of` from the predicate:

```
is_parent_of(X, Y) :- parent_of(X, Y).
is_parent_of(X, Y) :- parent_of(X, C), sibling(C, Y).
```

I don't think you need `C \= Y` here since your facts don't have anyone being their own sibling, so the check is superfluous. Likewise, it's superfluous to check to ensure we aren't capturing someone being their own parent.

With the above rules and your current database example, you get the results you want:

```
| ?- is_parent_of(X, Y).

X = warren
Y = jerry ? ;

X = maryalice
Y = jerry ? ;

X = warren
Y = stuart ? ;

X = warren
Y = kather ? ;

X = maryalice
Y = stuart ? ;

X = maryalice
Y = kather ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!!